# Is a multitude of questions to explain a youtube video ok?

Tags: support

I watched a video on youtube which makes satire of various planes, airlines and stuff. It is quite fast, each point being a few seconds only. I've found what I've understood hilarious, but there are many things I don't.

Could this site help me? Is it ok to make something along 10 bullets of possibly fast-to-answer questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general multi questions don't work well, because you will end up with many partial answers, none providing all the answers to the questions. How does voting work in such case? Which answer is acceptable?

The only way I could see it fit in the format of the site is that you answer your own multi question with Wiki answer. This wiki answer would then be used to aggregate the partial answers.

Personally I am not a big fan such a 'hack' but it could work in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what other users, or the moderators, would think about this, but one option would be to post a separate question for each thing you want to know about.